# C# still hooked to an event after unhooking

Tags: c#, events, memory-leaks, hook

I am currently debugging a big (very big!) C# application that contains memory leaks. It mainly uses Winforms for the GUI, though a couple of controls are made in WPF and hosted with an ElementHost. Until now, I have found that many of the memory leaks were caused by events not being unhooked (by calling -=) and I've been able to solve the problem.

However, I just came across a similar problem. There is a class called WorkItem (short lived) which in the constructor registers to events of another class called ClientEntityCache (long lived). The events were never unhooked and I could see in .NET profiler that instances of WorkItem were being kept alive when they shouldn't because of those events. So I decided to make WorkItem implement IDisposable and in the Dispose() function I unhook the events this way:

```
public void Dispose()
{
  ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared -= ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared;
  // Same thing for 10 other events
}
```

EDIT

Here is the code I use for subscription:

```
public WorkItem()
{
  ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared += ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared;
  // Same thing for 10 other events
}
```

I also changed the code for unregistering to not call new EntityCacheClearedEventHandler.

END OF EDIT

I made the calls to Dispose at the proper places in the code that uses WorkItem and when I debug I can see that the function is really being called and I do -= for every event. But I still get a memory leak and my WorkItems still stay alive after being Disposed and in .NET profiler I can see that the instances are kept alive because the event handlers (like EntityCacheClearedEventHandler) still have them in their invocation list. I tried to unhook them more than once (multiple -=) just to make sure they were not hooked more than once but this doesn't help.

Anyone has an idea why this is happening or what I could do to solve the problem?
I suppose I could change the event handlers to use weak delegates but this would require to mess a lot with a big pile of legacy code.

Thanks!

EDIT:

If this helps, here is the root path described by .NET profiler:
lots of things point on ClientEntityCache, which points to EntityCacheClearedEventHandler, which points to Object[], which points to another instance of EntityCacheClearedEventHandler (I don't understand why), which points to WorkItem.

Comment: Can you show us the event subscription code?

Comment: Is the Dispose being called from different threads?  Are you using a custom add/remove for the event?  The Delegate state cannot be corrupted (as it's immutable), but it is possible for multiple add or remove operations to interfere with one-another if you implement a custom add/remove and don't include the default implementation locking.

Comment: You might want to stop in the debugger and take a look at the invocation list (Delegate.GetInvocationList) and see how many event handlers are listed. There might be event handlers wired that are not bound to ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared but some other function.

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is referencing the WorkItems?  I'm not sure if implementing IDisposable is the best approach, the resources you're trying to dispose aren't unmanaged and should be released by the GC at the next cycle.  Have you tried just setting the delegate to null instead of trying to remove the event handlers?  Are there multiple handlers associated with the event?

Comment: @Marcus King: Yeah I'm sure nothing else is referencing the WorkItems. I can see in .NET profiler that the only thing referencing them are the event handlers. For the IDisposable I agree this might not be the best solution but I had no method to call to tell the WorkItem to unregister so I tried that. Maybe I should just create a method called CleanUp or something like that.

Comment: If you're calling dispose on the object then it seems like your intent is to destroy the whole thing, couldn't you just set the object to null and wait for garbage collection or call GC.Collect()
and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Comment: @Marcus King - NEVER call GC.Collect. That's a huge code smell.

Comment: @vcsjones I don't recommend calling it either but it sounds like if he's really worried about memory being used and want's fine grained control over when to release objects there really isn't any other option.  It's potentially dangerous but it may work for him.  You can't say NEVER use it. MS put it in the framework so it can be used for the right situation. Whether or not this is it is up for debate

Comment: @Marcus King: Setting the object to null was already done in the code and I still do it after calling my Dispose function. But still if I run my application for an hour or so, I got 100s of WorkItems alive when I really only need 1 or 2 at a time. So I checked what the problem was and .NET profiler tells me they are all kept alive even when set to null because of the events from ClientEntityCache from which I don't seem to be able to unregister. I don't call GC.collect() and I don't want to because I don't care when the WorkItems get collected, I just want them to be collected sometime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that multiple different delegate functions are wired to the event. Hopefully the following little example will make it clearer as to what I mean.

```
// Simple class to host the Event
class Test
{
  public event EventHandler MyEvent;
}

// Two different methods which will be wired to the Event
static void MyEventHandler1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}

static void MyEventHandler2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}


[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Test t = new Test();
  t.MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyEventHandler1);
  t.MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyEventHandler2); 

  // Break here before removing the event handler and inspect t.MyEvent

  t.MyEvent -= new EventHandler(MyEventHandler1);      
  t.MyEvent -= new EventHandler(MyEventHandler1);  // Note this is again MyEventHandler1    
}
```

If you break before the removal of the event handler you can view the invocation list in the debugger. See below, there are 2 handlers, one for MyEventHandler1 and another for the method MyEventHandler2.

[image]

Now after removing the MyEventHandler1 twice, MyEventHandler2 is still registered, because there is only one delegate left it looks a little different, it is no longer showing in the list, but until the delegate for MyEventHandler2 is removed it will still be referenced by the event.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying he needs to unhook all handlers in order to free up resources?

Comment: Thanks for the nice examples, but unfortunately this is not the case. After unregistering to the event the invocationList becomes null. So I guess everything seems alright, but I still don't understand why .NET profiler tells me the WorkItem is being kept alive because of a reference from EntityCacheClearedEventHandler.

Comment: Well, if the target object is being kept alive because the Event is still referencing a handler in the target object then yes he will need to remove all the handlers so that the Event no longer holds a reference to the target object and the target object can be released. Of course we do not see all the code, that is why I have tries to provide @Carl with the tools to investigate this aspect of the problem.

Comment: @Carl, be careful here. If there is only one delegate, then the _invocationList is null so it can be misleading. See the second screenshot, I do not show the _invocationList because it is null, but the Event is not null, it still references MyEventHandler2 and will do so until you say t.MyEvent -= new EventHandler(MyEventHandler2). Of course that is assuming that this is actually the problem you are facing.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. I just saw that the event is still referencing a method of another class ActivitiesWorkItem (which derives from WorkItem). I checked and there are instances of ActivitiesWorkItem and instances of WorkItem that register on the events of ClientEntityCache. I unregister them correctly in WorkItem, but I haven't done it yet for ActivitiesWorkItem. Is it possible that my WorkItem instances are kept alive because the ActivitiesWorkItem instances don't unregister from the event? I gotta say I'm having a hard time understanding the designs of the guy who created that app!

Comment: @Carl, it is very difficult without seeing more code. But basically, and I am sure you know this, the event will hold a reference to all the object instances that have a handler method attached to the event. So those objects will not be eligible for collection until they have removed themselves from the events that they have subscribed to. Of course if three object each have a subscription and only one of the objects need to be reclaimed only that object needs to unsubscribe so that the reference is no longer held to that object. So you would need to identify all the reference dependencies...

Comment: ...to know for sure what is keeping the object alive. If it was me stuck with this problem, I would use WinDBG to take a quick memory dump and then use the !gcroot command to find all the references that are still maintained to the target object. But that is quite advanced, and would be a last resort.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot for your help! I'll try to take a look with WinDBG but I've never used it.

Comment: There is still a thing I don't understand. I got this event handler problem a couple of times before and the result from .NET memory profiler was that MyEventHandler had its field _target set to MyInstance and so MyInstance was kept alive. What I got now is MyEventHandler which got its _invocationList pointing on an array of Object and one of those Object is another MyEventHandler which got its field _target pointing on MyInstance. (I'm not sure I should put this as a comment but I'm still new to StackOverflow and I don't know where else to put it lol).

Comment: It seems when I debug I can see that the event handler DOESN'T keep a reference to my WorkItems. I don't understand why .NET profiler tells me there is one, but it seems like my problem should be resolved if I trust the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

When unhooking an event, it needs to be the same delegate. Like this:

```
public class Foo
{
     private MyDelegate Foo = ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared;
     public void WorkItem()
     {
         ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared += Foo;
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared -= Foo;
     }
}
```

The reason is, what you are using is syntactic sugar for this:

```
public class Foo
{
     public void WorkItem()
     {
         ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared +=
new MyDelegate(ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared);
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared -=
new MyDelegate(ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared);
     }
}
```

So the `-=` doesn't unhook the original one you subscribed with because they are different delegates.

Comment: @vcjones, this is not the case, it does not need to be the same delegate instance. It just needs to be the same method that the original delegate contained.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
 public void Dispose()
    {
      ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared -= ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared;
      // Same thing for 10 other events
    }
```

You are creating a new event handler and removing it from the `delegate` - which effectively does nothing.

Remove the event subscription by removing reference to the ***original*** subscribing event method.

You could always just set your `eventhandler = delegate {};` In my opinion, that would be better than `null`.

Comment: Actually the compiler will implicitly add a `new EntityCacheClearedEventHandler(ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared)`.

Comment: I just tried registering by doing ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared += ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared; and unregistering by doing ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared -= ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared; instead of calling new EntityCacheClearedEventHandler but I got the same problem :(.

Comment: @Chaos: got a link? I want to look into that ... it doesn't make sense to do that ...

Comment: @IAbstract, using ILDASM you will see that the same IL is generated by the compiler for either syntax. The compiler emits the code to construct the delegate instance if it was not explicitly specified, so regardless of the C# syntax used the end result is `ClientEntityCache.EntityCacheCleared += new MyDelegate(ClientEntityCache_CacheCleared);`

Comment: @IAbstract, no problem. This is a common misconception and to be honest delegates and therefore events present in a non-intuitive way in this regard, one would definitely expect that you should remove the same reference, even the way `null` is handled is treated is not very intuitive and is often a topic of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you unhooking the right reference? When you unhook using `-=` no error is produced and if you're unhooking events which aren't hooked nothing will happen. However if you add using `+=` you'll get an error if the event is already hooked. Now, this is only a way for you to diagnose the problem but try adding the events instead and if you *DONT* get an error the problem is that your unhooking the event with the wrong reference.

Comment: I just tried doing += where I called -= and I get no error even though the debugger passes through that code. So does that mean I'm trying to unregister to the wrong event or...?

Comment: Yes, you're losing track of your references and that's why it doesn't work as you expect. Each delegate is unique and you need to register and unregister using the same delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Dispose won't get called by the GC if the instance is being kept alive by the event handlers, as it is still being referenced by the source of the events.

If you called your Dispose method yourself, the references would then go out of scope.

Comment: I call my Dispose method myself when I'm done with the WorkItems. I can see that it is being called when I debug. Still the references are kept.

Comment: calling Dispose will not cause the reference to go out of scope. Dispose might clear the internal state of the instance, but that does not affect the scope of the instance.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is that the object will not have its Dispose method called (by the framework), if it is being kept alive by event listeners.  Therefore, unwiring event handlers in this method, and expecting the GC to call it won't work.

Comment: If you call it yourself, descope your reference, and the objects are still alive, there must be another object holding a reference to it.